# for-cycle through extern plain array of unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, extern

I have a cpp file with the following code:

```
extern int global_values[] = {60, 67, 70};
```

I have another cpp file with the following:

```
extern int global_values[];
for (auto i: global_values) // or any other type of for loop
{
    // ... do something
}
```

and when I try to compile, I get the following error: `an array of unknown size cannot be used in a range-based for statement`. I know what the problem is and I understand that far behind the scenes the compiler would finally like to call something like `sizeof(global_values)/sizeof(int)` to get the number of steps but the first term is unknown. My question is how to solve it. And what is worst of all - the first cpp file with the array definition is outside my reach, I cannot change it. Is there a solution, I doubt it. But maybe I am missing something obvious and simple.

Comment: Um, just an idea - what about calling sizeof(global_values)/sizeof(int) in your code and then use old syntax of for cycle?

Comment: @IvoPeterka: That won't work for exactly the same reason. The size is only available in the same translation unit as the definition.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Yes, you are right.

Comment: "the array definition is outside my reach, I cannot change it" - the best solution is to bring it within your reach, and change it. Any other option will be an error-prone hack.

Comment: a) use an `std::array` b) use a myer's singleton which returns the array

Comment: @Mgetz: is any of these two suggestions possible without changing the first compilation unit?

Comment: @V.K. nope, the reason I suggested `std::array` is it means not having to put a length constant in a header as the array knows its own length.

Answer (score 0):

`extern int global_values[] = {` alone makes absolutely no sense because it's length is lost on linking stage. It needs to be rewritten into either `extern int global_values[3];` (in .h) or have companion variable added : `extern int global_values_length = sizeof(global_values)/sizeof(int)`.

But if this variable is already extern then maybe somebody is already using it externally and companion variable is already defined somewhere.

Comment: I think that `extern int global_values[3] = {...` would not work either. The compiler knows that the count is 3 from the list of initialized values. But this information is lost anyway during linkage. Probably will need to ask the counterparty responsible for this compilation unit to add another variable with the size.

Comment: yeah, it needs to be `extern int global_values[3];` in .h file not the .cpp one. My bad.